# How to open a menu with 'Open Terminal Here' in Ubuntu 10.04 by left clicking desktop, or inside folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-10.04, gnome

How can I customize Ubuntu 10.04 so the menu created by left clicking inside a folder or desktop gives me the option of opening up a terminal in that location? I have thsi functionality in the XFCE desktop on my Xubuntu 10.04 laptop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Install nautilus addon `nautilus-open-terminal`.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

Comment: Cool thanks but it doesn't take effect right away. You have to restart Gnome by entering "sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart" into terminal. Once Gnome loads back up it works fine :) Thanks.

Comment: @Adam: You don't have to restart GNOME, just Nautilus (`nautilus -q` should do the trick).