# How to 'Open Nautilius Here' in Ubuntu 10.04 from terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, nautilus

I know how to open terminal while being in Nautilius: [How to open a menu with 'Open Terminal Here' in Ubuntu 10.04 by left clicking desktop, or inside folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/166407/how-to-open-a-menu-with-open-terminal-here-in-ubuntu-10-04-by-left-clicking-de)

I'd like to do the other way round: while being in certain directory in terminal I'd like to open Nautilius in that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
nautilus .
```

In Unix-like systems **.** represents the current directory and **..** the parent directory.

Comment: fast and furious

Comment: @MarianPaździoch You may wish to add an &, which puts the application (nautilus, in this case) into the background, so that you are free to continue use the terminal when you wish to.